# Test-specific Application subclass

Tags: android, android-testing, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to have an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) subclass that's used only for tests when building with gradle? I've done something like this in the past before the gradle build system, but I can't find a way to do so now. The problem seems to be that it's impossible to customize the `AndroidManifest.xml` used for the instrumentation test APK.

Comment: dagger modifies the androidmanifest.xml file and Google devs are in fact using dagger with the espresso release test framework so yes its possible to customize the androidmanifest..you just have to experiment in how

Comment: I've done a fair amount of experimenting and research and not had any success, hence my question and the bounty.

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the manifest of test APK? Both the test code and the app code are in the same VM, so I would expect there to only be one `Application` singleton, defined by the app's manifest. Isn't this a matter of tailoring the app's manifest in a dedicated build type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create build variants which would at let you have a different version of the Application class and let you override the manifest. You could then test only that specific variant. http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

"For instance, if the flavors are used to generate a ads-based app and a paid app, one of the flavors could have a dependency on an Ads SDK, while the other does not.

dependencies {
    flavor1Compile "..."
}
In this particular case, the file src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml would probably need to include the internet permission."